# Is there a way to dynamically turn class variable values into string literal types (in Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, casting

For example, if I have a class

```
export class SlideOutComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() footerActions: {
    buttonType?: "link" | "wire";
    name: string;
  }[];

  @Output() footerAction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  emitAction(name: SlideOutComponent["footerActions"][number]["name"]) {

  }

}
```

is there a way to dynamically create a string literal type based off what the user passes in for the name fields? (The above example only return the type *string*)

Here is how this user would pass in the fields:

Template

```
<slide-out
  [footerActions]="footerActions"
>
</slide-out>
```

TS

```
export class ListPageComponent implements OnInit {

  footerActions = [
  {
    buttonType: "link",
    name: "Close"
  },
  {
    name: "Add"
  }
];


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
```

So, I would want to dynamically produce `type Names = "Close" | "Add"`

Comment: You can try with any.

Comment: name: any; like this

Comment: Where does the user "pass in" the fields?  Can you show a [mcve] where this is being used?

Comment: @AmanGojariya, That won't give me the type-safety I'm seeking. Please look up string literal types.

Comment: @jcalz I added an example.

Comment: Wait, your example does not use `SlideOutComponent` at all.  Is `ListPageComponent` supposed to extend `SlideOutComponent`?  And are you intentionally making `footerActions` an uninitialized tuple type?   (You are writing `footerActions: [...]` and not `footerActions = [...]`, so I'm not sure I get it).  Ideally I could drop the code into a standalone IDE and see what you are doing.

Comment: I mean, is [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wzy5rm) what you're looking for?  If not, please elaborate.

Comment: @jcalz yes sorry, i meant to write *footerActions =* ... And it uses the slide out component  in the template (this is an angular example if it wasnt clear). You're adding the "as const"?

Comment: I think I'd need to see a working example in an IDE before I could go further, since I am not sure how type inference works with angular.  At the very least you will need to write `as const` or something like it in `ListPageComponent` , otherwise the compiler will widen the string literals to `string` and you'll be lost before you even started.

Comment: @jclaz this isnt the best example to ask it...I will post a new question and ref it here

Comment: @jcalz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680762/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-value-from-a-specific-key-in-a-type-declaration-as-the

Comment: @AaronTurkel you've explicitly said the the type of `name` is `string` in your `footerActions` type, so I suspect that the answer is "no, it's not possible".  It would help a lot if you could put this in a CodeSandbox as myself and others aren't really Angular pros.  I tried copy and pasting it but I'm getting errors like "Can't bind to 'footerActions' since it isn't a known property of 'slide-out'."