# Is there a way to use the value from a specific key in a type declaration as the type of another key in that same declaration (in Typescript)?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, casting, type-conversion

Let's say I'm trying to create a Variable type that takes a *type* key which has a type of *string*: is there a way to access the value from the key called *type* and use that as the type for another key in that type declaration? (Without using Generic Types)

For example,

```
type Variable = {
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
  type: string;
  defaultValue: Variable["type"];
}

const newWorkingVar: Variable = {
  name: "count",
  required: true,
  type: "number",
  defaultValue: 22 // This should work
}

const newErrorVar: Variable = {
  name: "count",
  required: true,
  type: "number",
  defaultValue: "test" // This should error
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to understand that the string `"number"` has anything to do with the type `number`?  I suppose you could build a mapping and then make a union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND5y6m), but I don't know if this is what you're looking for.  Could you explain the parenthetical "without using generic types" requirement at the end?  It's a bit like saying "I have a can of soup I'd like to open (without using this can opener)".  It might be *possible*, but you'd have more luck if you can explain why your use case precludes can openers, uh, generics.

Comment: The use case would be to have a simple JSON object that could also be editable in Typescript with type-safety. I would need to set the type in the JSON object (and read that value), not just use it for type-safety. But your example works! Thank you for the answer, it is more generic but not as succinct as @Linda Paste

Comment: @jcalz If you post your solution with an explanation it would be helpful for me and, I'm sure, others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is similar to @LindaPaiste's, with the minor change that the mapping from names to types is kept in a separate type, which is then manipulated to produce `Variable`.  For example, your mapping could look like this:

```
type TypeMapping = {
  number: number;
  string: string;
  boolean: boolean
  // add more here as needed
}
```

And then `Variable` could be

```
type Variable = { [K in keyof TypeMapping]: {
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
  type: K;
  defaultValue: TypeMapping[K];
} }[keyof TypeMapping]
```

This works by taking each key `K` from `TypeMapping` and transforming the property type from `TypeMapping[K]` to the subtype of `Variable` for that `K` (where `type` is the key and `defaultValue` is the property type).  The resulting [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) is not exactly what we want because it still has the same keys as `TypeMapping`.  We get the union of its properties by [indexing into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

Result:

```
/* type Variable = {
    name: string;
    required: boolean;
    type: "string";
    defaultValue: string;
} | {
    name: string;
    required: boolean;
    type: "number";
    defaultValue: number;
} | {
    name: string;
    required: boolean;
    type: "boolean";
    defaultValue: boolean;
} */
```

And now you get the behavior you're looking for:

```
const newWorkingVar: Variable = {
  name: "count",
  required: true,
  type: "number",
  defaultValue: 22 // okay
}

const newErrorVar: Variable = {
  name: "count",
  required: true,
  type: "number",
  defaultValue: "test" // error!
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYwEsB2BzKBeKA3gFBRQYCuAtgEYQBOAXGVbXQNwlQDOwdmWTHn2wdS1APbiANhCQYmE6bIxEAvkSKhIUAGpI+SajLyEoAbQDSUTFADWEEOIBmseMlT8Auk2KkMSSghBXn5RKDoIAEdyNAiAEwVJGTkwrSCoCzC4iCckcilgPSlydLhId3RsS08OVShVM3tHFzLEFEqsTw0iAHoAKig03X00Q2N8X1IyAPShUM5SCOjYiASoRWSMMNI0pgAiOew97ahs3PzCpGLZkJE1KAAfQgXpwODhLBOlmPjEpRSXrsoHsKDR6McXmc8gUiiUmKDWLVHs8pq8bh8vlEfqs-psTkC9htlBDUVCLrD0kSAXU+j0NABjcQYHhkCAAdwA6uI6LZ+HpGMMDEZoBNOP43sDGeQMMA9gAaTjfFZrXglBU7eD7BHg9WnHLQy7XJgAJmNUB6PVgAAs0FxuFbxPk4lA2dzbGoGUyWRh2QBROh0bn8pj80bCkyTcXpPZSmXyxVY5VMVUQXUE7V0eOkMkwq5w4HACA8Pbmy0wG12rgOp1QeiBuhqIA)

Answer (score 3):

Without generics you would need to have a union of all valid pairings of `type` and `defaultValue`.

```
type Pair = 
  | { type: "number", defaultValue: number }
  | { type: "string", defaultValue: string }
  | { type: "user", defaultValue: User }

type Variable = {
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
} & Pair;
```

This will get you the error that you want on `{type: "number", defaultValue: "test"}` as that is not assignable to any member of the `Pair` union.

> Type '{ name: string; required: true; type: "number"; defaultValue: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Variable'.
>
> Types of property 'defaultValue' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Unfortunately there is not a way (that I know of) to associate types with their string names, so you need to build the `Pair` union manually.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N7b1Rw)